# Set secured field in javascript according to general attribute

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016, xrm

My mission is: if the owner of the record is loading the form nothing changes but if not the record's owner loading the form so a X field must be a 'secured field' (can see the field not the value on form and not on advanced search) - is it possible ? I'm not sure that it is possible because on advanced search it will not look at the record's owner data.

A solution that I thought about is when the form is loading I will check if the user is the owner and if so I will give him a security role or add him to a team that has the privilege to my secured field, is it sounds logical?
Is there an other option to solve that case ?

Comment: Did you try this?

Answer (score 0):

This is a tricky requirement, because we need Field level security enabled for that attribute and based on some field value in a record (owner) - the user will get access to the secured field. But usually FLS will give permission for set of users/team configured in FLS profile. We cannot create a team for each record, Access team cannot be used for this, Security role is not helpful in this scenario.

[Similar topic discussed](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/microsoft-dynamics-crm-forum/167317/share-secured-fields-via-workflow) on community forum and [this blog post](https://zhongchenzhou.wordpress.com/2012/06/28/dynamics-crm-2011-share-secured-fields/) talks about using sdk call to utilize “Share secured fields” functionality.

You can use similar snippet in plugin/workflow/Javascript for sharing it with owner on create/update. This will work in form, advanced find and everywhere.

```
Entity poaa = new Entity("principalobjectattributeaccess");
 poaa["attributeid"] = attributeResponse.AttributeMetadata.MetadataId;
 poaa["objectid"] = new EntityReference(entityName, objectId);
 poaa["readaccess"] = allowRead;
 poaa["updateaccess"] = allowUpdate;
 if (shareWithTeam)
 {
 poaa["principalid"] = new EntityReference("team", principalId);
 }
 else
 {
 poaa["principalid"] = new EntityReference("systemuser", principalId);
 }
 
service.Create(poaa);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work. Give it a try please.

- Set up a Retrieve and RetrieveMultiple plugins
- Set the plugins to run as current user
- In plugin code, if current user and owner are different, simply remove the value from the specified field.

**NOTE**

- Retrieve plugin works for forms.
- RetrieveMultiple plugin works for advanced find and views.
- Find sample plugin code for Retrieve and RetrieveMultiple plugin on google. Modify it according to your above requirement.